# Update a value from Subquery to field of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a field with the value from the subquery, I am using the following :

```
UPDATE t_c_contract
SET _country_code = (SELECT country_code FROM t_b_country WHERE some_condition) WHERE cid = @cid
```

The Subquery provides a single value but I am getting the error that 'there are multiple values and '=' is not allowed'

Is this not a correct format to assign a value of sub-query to the table-field?

Comment: The subquery on the RHS of the set assignment returns more than one value.  Check your data to see why this might be happening.

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE, not correlated subquery. *The Subquery provides a single value but I am getting the error that 'there are multiple values and '=' is not allowed'* This means that you're wrong, and it selects more than one value for some rows. `WHERE some_condition` must include joining condition. Also you may add `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: are you sure your sub-query returns one value?. Cuz if you doubt it just run the sub-query in an stand alone mode and make sure you have one value

Comment: One question : 
```t_c_contract``` is your table name and ```_country_code``` is your field right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an `update` statement using sub queries, Which works fine for me. With the conditions in sub query I get only one value,

> this is actually the principle of `COPY` in SQL. I copy
> UserAccessControls from one user to another

```sql
UPDATE UserAccessControls
    SET
    UA_CanInsert = (SELECT UA_CanInsert FROM UserAccessControls WHERE UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue AND UA_user_key_r = @first_user_id),
    UA_CanUpdate = (SELECT UA_CanUpdate FROM UserAccessControls WHERE UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue AND UA_user_key_r = @first_user_id),
    UA_CanDelete = (SELECT UA_CanDelete FROM UserAccessControls WHERE UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue AND UA_user_key_r = @first_user_id),
    UA_CanView = (SELECT UA_CanView FROM UserAccessControls WHERE UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue AND UA_user_key_r = @first_user_id),
    UA_CanOpen = (SELECT UA_CanOpen FROM UserAccessControls WHERE UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue AND UA_user_key_r = @first_user_id)
    WHERE
        UA_user_key_r = @second_user_id
        AND
        UA_menu_id_r = @menuMinValue
```

This works fine so it shows that you need to check your sub query's `SOME CONDITION`

Comment: Hmm I checked the condition, it is showing me only one value. Strangely the error says otherwise. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @PallaviChowdhary You are welcome, but I still think there should be something wrong with your sub-query condition

Answer (score 0):

I believe the database.  You can check, of course, by running:

```
select c.*, 
       (select count(*) from t_b_country bc where <some_condition>) as cnt
from t_c_contract c
where cid = @cid
having cnt > 1
order by cnt desc
```

To fix your query, just select one of the matching rows:

```
UPDATE t_c_contract
    SET _country_code = (SELECT country_code
                         FROM t_b_country
                         WHERE some_condition
                         LIMIT 1
                        )
    WHERE cid = @cid ;
```

Of course, this only masks what might be an error in your data.  So I suggest that you investigate the cause of the duplicates so you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I would suggest using a JOIN instead of sub-query:

```
UPDATE  t_c_contract
SET     _country_code   =   country.country_code 
FROM    t_c_contract    AS  T
JOIN    t_b_country     AS  country
    ON  some_condition
WHERE   T.cid           =   @cid
```